# What is replacement of NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval() in swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, nstimer

I want to implement NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in Swift 3. I want to know the Replacement of

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.35, target: self, selector: #selector(createEnemy), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

as we used it in swift 2.2

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.35, target: self, selector: #selector(createEnemy), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Thanx :) its more concise then swift 2.2

Answer (score -1):

You may also used with instance of Timer, if you want to invalidate as per your requirement.

```
//Create Timer instance
var objTimer = Timer()

//Schedule Timer
self.objTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTriggered), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//Invalidate Timer after task complete
self.objTimer.invalidate()
```

Comment: The question has already been answered, and it was not about invalidation.